# Can we have primary key - foreign key relation ship between normal tables and external polybase tables in one database?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, sql-server-2016, parquet, external-tables, polybase

Can we have both normal tables and external tables in one database with primary key - foreign key relation ship between them? The external table is backed by blob storage and the file format is parquet. 
If we can have relation what if some one directly access the parquet file from blob and update it?

Comment: Doesn't seems we can as external table are not supporting primary keys.